# HTTP caching questions

Tags: http, asp-classic

I am  using response header to make sure that the page is not cached on the browser end, i have used the following code to do that.
Can some one please let me know following,

1. How to to test if its working ? or not working?
2. Does it also stops the caching for CSS and JS fils.
3. Can some one please elaborate how this caching works ? in windows we have templerary internet files does it has something to do with this.

   `Response.CacheControl = "no-cache, no-store";`

   `Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");`

   `Response.Expires = -1;`

Comment: What actual header fields does this code produce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go read [Mark Nottingham's excellent tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).

```
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache, no-store";
```

should be

```
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
```

and

```
 Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
```

is meaningless - despite it being suggested by lots of sites ([Manual](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) - it's a REQUEST header - not a response header).

```
 Response.Expires = -1;
```

Is only relevant to HTTP/1.0 clients - most major browsers still respect the HTTP/1.1 responses (cache-control) headers even when using the HTTP/1.0 stack. In the absence of caching information a brwser should not cache the response. Therefore it should be perfectly safe to omit this.

> How to to test if its working ?

Look at your webserver log files or use wireshark or iehttpheaders to see if the browsers going back to the server every time the content is referenced

> Does it also stops the caching for CSS and JS fils.

Yes - caching information is independent of the name of the file and its mimetype.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no way to make sure nothing is cached by the browser**

By all means you can direct the browser not to with response headers, but you can't guarantee it will work on all browsers in all scenarios.

If you explain the reasons (preventing use of the backbutton?) we can come up with a decent solution.

Answer (score 0):

A partial match: to check your response headers, if you use Firefox, I recommend you the Firebug extension, with it you can trace the whole HTTP cycle, including request and response headers, and the HTTP response status code.